# Converting errors

Tags: c#, arrays, function

I need some help with a couple of errors I'm receiving for C# in Visual Studio. They state cannot convert string to int or cannot convert int to char. Would someone be able to assist me with this, please?

```
        Console.WriteLine(" The largest value in the array is ", numberArray, maximumIndex, "located at array index" + maximumIndex);

        //Loop through the two arrays and print the integer from integer array followed by the corresponding value from the string array
        Console.WriteLine(" The numbers were: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.Length; i++)

            Console.WriteLine(numberArray[i], " is ", stringArray[i]); **Getting error for "numberArray"-Cannot convert 'int' to 'char; Getting error for "is"-Cannot convert string to int; Getting error for "stringArray"-Cannot convert string to int**
```

Comment: Instead of commas, use + in those writelines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**C# approach**
Though the (,) operator may be used in python or in some other languages, the (,) operator is not really a C# syntax within the Console.[method] arguments.

**Solutions**
You may use any of these approaches, it's all about preference. I will rank them from my favorite approach to the other possible approaches:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{numberArray[i]} is {stringArray[i]}");
// Example output: 1 is 2
```

That's the cleanest solution in my opinion. But another would be the use of **[Concatination](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/chash-string-concat-with-examples)**

```
Console.WriteLine(numberArray[i] + " is " + stringArray[i]);
// Example output: 1 is 2
```

Hope this helped. More ways of approaching this topic exist but these are the two worth telling you about at the moment, can't think of any more comfortable version but I'm sure they exist.

Comment: No brackets is legal: the definition is `for(...) statement;`, where statement is singular. One example of such a statement is the compound statement: `{`, 0-or-more statements, `}`. But yes, as a matter of style it is best to always include those `{ }`, that way it is clear what belongs to that "for" and what doesn't

Comment: I'll edit the answer. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

you need to do + in the console.writeline not a ,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code as below;

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numberArray = {1, 5, 10};
            var maximumIndex = 2;

            Console.WriteLine("The largest value in the array is {0} {1} located at array index{2}", string.Join(",", numberArray), maximumIndex, maximumIndex);
        }
```

Output: The largest value in the array is 1,5,10 2 located at array index2

refer [Interpolated String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)